# Global string validation in ASP.NET core to black-list some characters

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have an ASP.NET app running under .NET Core 3.1.

I would like to black-list globally some characters for (example ASCII NUL (0x0), SOH (0x1), backspace,... )

I would like an idea of overriding a string model binder if there is such a feature.

Is there any simple way?

Comment: TLDR; Implement `IModelBinderProvider`, return an `IModelBinder` for `typeof(string)`, and insert it into mvc's ModelBinderProviders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1. I've previously done the same just to trim all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing strings with your own model binder is fairly simple.

```cs
public class MyBinder : IModelBinderProvider, IModelBinder
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context) =>
        (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string)) ? this : null;
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (value != ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);
                var str = value.FirstValue;
                if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                    str = null;
                // TODO strip out invalid characters here
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(str);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyBinder());
```

If you want to return failure instead of silently modifying strings. You could either implement a validation attribute and remember to use it everywhere...

Or implement `IModelValidatorProvider` and add your `IModelValidator` to each bound string value.